# vuejs boolean props watch doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a vue cli project where items have two state equipped and unequipped.

This State is controlled by a Boolean located in the Props. Since you can switch the state I had to create a data isEquipped set to false by default.

I then added a watcher but it doesn't change my data value if my props is set to True.

Here's the code

```
name: "Item",
        props: {
            Index : Number,
            name: String,
            desc : String,
            bonus: Array,
            equipped  : Boolean
        },
        data() {
            return {
                isEquipped : false
            }
        },
        watch: {
            equipped: function(stateEquipped) {
                this.isEquipped = stateEquipped;
            },
        },
```

So for instance let's say I created a new item with equipped set to True, the watcher doesn't trigger and isEquipped stays at False, is there any reason to that ?

I came across multiple similar questions like this one [Vue @Watch not triggering on a boolean change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270456/vue-watch-not-triggering-on-a-boolean-change) but none of them helped me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use watch then you can try define it as:

```
equipped: {
    handler () {
        this.isEquipped = !this.isEquipped;
    },
    immediate: true
}
```

This will change the value of `this.isEquipped` whenever the value of equipped will change.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a [computed value](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) instead?

```js
{
  // ...
  computed: {
    isEquipped () {
      // loaded from the component's props
      return this.equipped
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use `isEquipped` in your components just as if it was defined in your `data()` method. You could also just use `equipped` in your components directly as you don't transform it in any way.

```html
<p>Am I equipped? - <b>{{ equipped }}</b></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the use case of `isEquipped` but seeing your code you can use the props directly unless there is a situation where you want to mutate the `isEquipped` that is not related to the props.

Answer (score -1):

Watchers are "slow" and they operate on vue's next life-cycle tick which can result in hard to debug reactivity problems.

There are cases where you need them, but if you find any other solution, that uses vue's reactivity system, you should consider using that one instead.

The solution using a computed value from @chvolkmann probably also works for you.

There is a imho better way to do this:

```js
export default {
  name: "Item",
  props: {
    Index : Number,
    name: String,
    desc : String,
    bonus: Array,
    equipped  : Boolean
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isEquipped : false
    }
  },
  updated () {
    if (this.equipped !== this.isEquipped) {
      this.isEquipped = this.equipped
      // trigger "onEquip" event or whatever
    }
  }
}
```

The `updated` life-cycle hook is called -as the name suggests- when a component is updated.
You compare the (unchanged) `isEquipped` with the new `equipped` prop value and if they differ, you know that there was a change.